# In what order are digital certificates verified?

Tags: tls, digital-signature

I understand how digital signatures work and how they are verified, but in what order does the CA verify each of the attributes of the digital certificate such as version, issuer, validity etc..?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: CAs only validate information when they are signing a certificate. All other validation is done by your browser (or other HTTPS client) at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It validates all of them at the same time. This is called a [Distinguished Name](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/survival/ssl.html#x509-overview).